# Run C++ application in mac terminal without window gaining focus?

Tags: c++, macos, matlab, terminal, executable

I was wondering if there is a way to execute a c++ application in the mac terminal either: without the executable window gaining focus or, without the executable window at all?

The application in question does not have any graphics, merely runs through some code and writes data.

I am currently running the executable in MATLAB like this:

```
[status,out] = system('./vevpd-opt *.pro');
```

And here is the window (there is nothing graphically associated with this window) appearing in my dock (exec - vevpd-opt):

[image]

The executable is being run multiple times as part of an optimisation procedure so gains focus multiple times per second, rendering the rest of the computer unusable while the script is running. If there is a way to prevent this from occurring I would be very grateful!

Comment: Once you've started the program, nothing stops you from doing something else meanwhile. You can even minimize the window and check your email or something. It doesn't matter how long the program takes, it will still continue to chug along in the background.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. The issue is I'm using the program in an optimisation procedure. I'm using MATLAB to perform the optimisation which executes this application thousands of times. So every time the program is executed by the optimisation script it gains focus and thus I can't actually do anything in the background :)

Comment: That is pretty important information that should be in the body of the question.

Comment: Ok I will edit the body, however the question remains the same.